# SQL pyodbc. Получение словаря из названия столбца и данных из SQL BD

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, словари

Есть запрос к базе данных:

```py
import pyodbc

def сonnector():

    connection_string = "DRIVER={drv};SERVER={srv};DATABASE={db};UID={uid};PWD={pwd}".\
             format(drv="{SQL Server}",
                    srv=server,
                    db=dbname,
                    uid=login,
                    pwd=password)
    cnxn = pyodbc.connect(connection_string)

    return cnxn

def fim_fx_get_full_info(AccountName):

     db = connector()

     cursor = db.cursor()
     cursor.execute("""SELECT AccountName,
                              Mail
                         FROM Table2
                        WHERE AccountName = '{}';""".format(AccountName))

     rows = cursor.fetchone()

     if rows != None:
         print(rows)
```

Который корректно отрабатывает, но выводит только значения из столбцов `AccountName` и `Mail`:

```
('username', 'username@domain.com')
```

Можно ли как-то получить вывод в виде словаря `{'ColumnName': 'ColumnData'}`?

Так как столбцов в таблице тьма и хотелось обращаться к данным по ключу:

```
({'AccountName':'username', 'Mail':'username@domain.com'})
```

Comment: это достаточно просто делается при помощи модуля Pandas...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример с использованием модуля Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pyodbc

# pyodbc
#
# assuming the following:
# username: scott
# password: tiger
# DSN: mydsn
engine = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://scott:tiger@mydsn')

# pymssql
#
#engine = create_engine('mssql+pymssql://scott:tiger@hostname:port/dbname')

df = pd.read_sql("select * from table_name", engine)
records = df.to_dict("records")
```

---

Результат будет приблизительно таким:

```
In [5]: df.to_dict("records")
Out[5]:
[{'username': 'user1', 'email': 'user1@domain.com'},
 {'username': 'user2', 'email': 'user2@domain.com'},
 {'username': 'user3', 'email': 'user3@domain.com'}]
```